# Slow animation in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
label = Label(screen, image = "")
label.pack()
num = 0

num = 0
img = None
def animate():
    global num
    global img
    img = PhotoImage(file = "gif.gif", format = "gif -index {}".format(num))
    label.configure(image = img)
    num = (num+1)%180
    screen.after(1, animate)
animate()

screen.mainloop()
```

The animation itself works, but it gets slower and slower considering I put a delay of 1 millisecond.
A recommended solution would be not to import other libraries, but go ahead if u know it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I didn't see the animation get slower, it did use a lot of memory. I found loading the frames first and then animating the image resulted in much lower memory usage, as you are not opening and processing an image every millisecond.
Here is the amended code:

```
label = Label(screen, image = "")
label.pack()
num = 0
img = None
frames = [PhotoImage(file = "gif.gif", format = "gif -index {}".format(num)) for num in range(180)]
def animate():
    global num
    global img
    label.configure(image = frames[num])
    num = (num+1)%180
    screen.after(100, animate)
animate()

screen.mainloop()
```

I would not recommend setting `screen.after` to 1 millisecond as this makes the gif too fast. I found 100ms was fast enough.

Comment: It did solve the animation slowness, but now there is another problem: It takes around 10 seconds for the tkinter root to open. Can I speed this up?

Comment: @YarinB I think that is the time it takes to load all 180 frames of the gif, I don't think it can be made much quicker